# mysql select update

Tags: mysql, select, append

Got this:

```
Table a
ID RelatedBs
1  NULL
2  NULL

Table b
AID ID
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
```

Need Table a to have a comma separated list as given in table b. And then table b will become obsolete:

```
Table a
ID RelatedBs
1  1,2,3
2  4,5,6
```

This does not rund through all records, but just ad one 'b' to 'table a'

```
UPDATE a, b
SET relatedbs = CONCAT(relatedbs,',',b.id)
WHERE a.id = b.aid
```

UPDATE: Thanks, 3 correct answers (marked oldest as answer)! GROUP_CONCAT is the one to use. No need to insert commas between the ids using relatedids = CONCAT(relatedids,',',next_id) that is done automatic by GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: To be honest, that's probably a poor choice in the way you manage your database. Not to say you can't do it, but the idea of foreign keys is to do exactly what you have, not what you're trying to do.

What's your motivation? Your queries will be significantly more convoluted if you ever need to get the `RelatedBs` and use them in the SQL.

Comment: True. But I still use comma separeted ids quite often when it is a one-2-many relation. When it is a many-2-many relation I allways use an mm-table to handle the relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the mysql group_concat function in order to achieve this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

Look into GROUP_CONCAT(expr)

```
mysql> SELECT student_name,
    ->        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
    ->                     ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR " ")
    ->        FROM student
    ->        GROUP BY student_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in standard SQL. You could write a stored procedure to do that. I had a similar problem, but I was using PostgreSQL so I was able to resolve it by writing a custom aggregate function so that you can do queries like

```
select aid, concat(id) 
from b group by
aid
```

Update: MySQL has a group_concat aggregate function so you can do something like

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) FROM services WHERE id = 3 GROUP BY id
```

as outlined [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/).